# Pass php value to other php file based on click in js

Tags: javascript, php

I got such code in index.php

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX");
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT posts.id, posts.title FROM posts");
    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != NULL) {
        echo '<div class="question" id="', $row["id"], '">', $row["title"], '</div>';
}
            ?>
```

Than later on I got:

```
<script>        
    var question = document.getElementsByClassName("question");
    for (var i = 0; i < question.length; ++i) {
        question[i].myParam = question[i].id;
        question[i].addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
            // TODO: Pass evt.currentTarget.myParam to question.php
            window.location.href = "/question.php";
        }, false);
    }
</script>
```

Do you know how to solve this todo?

Comment: use `GET`? `/question.php?foo=bar&hello=world`

Comment: And `<a href="` tag will do this __without__ javascript codes.

Comment: @u_mulder But as I said, I need to pass id to php file

Comment: `$_GET['id']` is available in php file `/question.php?id=42`